# Show there exist a constant $c\in \Bbb{C}$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}|{f-c}|^2<{1\over 36}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{C}$ be a $1$-periodic function, $f\in C^1$ and $\int_{0}^{1}|f'|^2\le 1$.

a. Show $\sum_{k\ne 0}|{\hat{f}(n)}|^2\le {1\over 4\pi^2}$ (I did it already, and that question is also available somewhere on this website).

b. Show there exist a constant $c\in \Bbb{C}$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}|{f-c}|^2<{1\over 36}$.

This is where I am stuck; I know that $\int_{0}^{1}|f|^2=\sum_{k\in \Bbb{Z}}|{\hat{f}(n)}|^2\le {1\over 4\pi^2}<{1\over 36}$ and I also know that $\int_{0}^{1}|{f-c}|^2\le \int_{0}^{1}|f|^2$ for any constant (that, actually, I am not sure of. It is the complex after all.). If the last inequality actually holds, then it works for any $c\in \Bbb{C}$. If it doesn't- why doesn't it, and how do I find such a $c$?

Comment: And why can't I just take $0$ to be that constant? 
It feels like I can't because it shouldn't be that simple.

Comment: Excuse my mistake. I revised it.

Comment: Yes, I did. Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $m=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ be the mean value of $f$ over $[0,1]$. By considering the Fourier series of $f$ we have:

$$f(x) = m +\sum_{n\geq 1}\left( s_n \sin(2\pi n x) + c_n \cos(2\pi n x)\right)$$
and:
$$ \| f'(x) \|^2 = 2\pi^2\sum_{n\geq 1} n^2 (s_n^2+c_n^2)\leq 1 $$
hence:
$$ \| f(x) - m\|^2 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}(s_n^2+c_n^2)\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}n^2(s_n^2+c_n^2)\leq\frac{1}{4\pi^2}<\frac{1}{36} $$
so a good choice for your constant $c$ is just $c=m=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$.

This is just [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\sum_{k\ne 0}|{\hat{f}(n)}|^2\le {1\over 4\pi^2}$, then you only need to consider $|\hat{f}(0)|$ and you can then apply Parseval's theorem linking the sum of the Fourier Coefficients with the Integral of the function squared. So if you can modify $f$ by adding a constant to make $\hat{f}(0) = 0$, you should be good to go...

Comment: What about taking $c=0$? Then I am dealing with $\int_{0}^{1}|f|^2=\sum_{k\ne 0}|{\hat{f}(n)}|^2\le {1\over 4\pi^2}<{1\over 36}$, aren't I?

Comment: You are right. I was wrong in my notes.

Comment: Can you give me another lead? I am a bit weak in that area.

Comment: Should I take $c=f(0)$?

Comment: I will take it as a "yes" for now. Still not entirely sure.